# Paypal: Reports - Download History using API

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to automate the process of downloading the paypal History (Reports - Download History) using the API? 
Currently based on the searches I've made I'm using TransactionSearchReq() to fetch the data but I guess this is not the right call. Can someone please point me on how to get the report data using API. I'm using C# (VS2012).

```
TransactionSearchReq req = new TransactionSearchReq();
req.TransactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType();
req.TransactionSearchRequest.StartDate =   System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
req.TransactionSearchRequest.EndDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();
TransactionSearchResponseType responseType = service.TransactionSearch(req);

<account apiUsername="jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com" apiPassword="WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F" applicationId="APP-80W284485P519543T" apiSignature="AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy"/>
<account apiUsername="certuser_biz_api1.paypal.com" apiPassword="D6JNKKULHN3G5B8A" applicationId="APP-80W284485P519543T" apiCertificate="C:\PayPal_SDKs\sdk-core-dotnet\UnitTest\Resources\sdk-cert.p12" privateKeyPassword="password"/>
```

Thanks For your help in advance
Josh

Comment: A combination of TransactionSearch and GetTransactionDetails should do it for you.  Why are you thinking TransactionSearch isn't correct?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had spent a lot of time searching on google, some said this cannot be done using the API and more over the TransactionSearch did not return all the fields that I see when I download the report, which might now be solved when I use the GetTransactionDetails. Also can you please tell me how do I generate the applicationID for paypal?  <account apiUsername="jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com" apiPassword="WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F" applicationId="APP-80W284485P519543T"
               apiSignature="AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy"/>

Comment: After reading a few posts I found out that applicationid is not required for me. The only question I have now is how do I get more than 100 rows using TransactionSearch?

Comment: You can't, you just need to shrink the search range and then make multiple calls to get the entire set.

Comment: Andrew, when I call GetTransactionDetails using paypalAPIInterfaceSvc.GetTransactionDetails(tranxDetailReq); I get only one transaction result, but when I download the report from the web interface I see 2 tranactions (Debit and Credit) for that tranactionid. Do you know why GetTransactionDetails is not returning both the records using API? I also have this option set in the code                     List<DetailLevelCodeType?> dRpt = new List<DetailLevelCodeType?>();
                    dRpt.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.RETURNALL);
                    getTransactionDetailsRequest.DetailLevel = dRpt;

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying there.  I need to see a sample of what you're talking about.